# MySQL import error

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to import a `wordpress` database to other server, but that server have old `phpMyAdmin 2.5.6` version.

When I am importing that database I am getting

```
error :#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax near 'SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"' at line 1
```

When I comment that line out, I get another error.

Is there any way to get it work on this server?

**Thanks, I fixed it. 
I used a SQL compatibility mode - MYSQL323**

Comment: Could you show us the entire query? Something goes wrong before SQL_MODE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a phpmyadmin problem, but is related to your MySQL export.
When you have exported the database, how do you have setup the export method ?  Seems like you have a Mysql 5.0 dump and try to import in a MySQL versione that is older.

I suggest you to export your database with "**Compatibiliy Mode**" NONE, if you use phpmyadmin to export it!

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to the version of phpMyadmin but to the version of MySQL.
You are probably trying to import a DB from a more recent version of MySQL, hence some options not recognized here.

phpMyadmin (on the previous server) should have some options that allow you to make your export more compatible with older versions of MySQL.